# Can I use an array in a case statement?

Tags: c++, arrays, switch-statement, case

I would like to use an array of const int in a switch/case statement in C++. Is it possible? So far I've tried something like:

```
int main()
{
    int const tab[3] = {1,2,3};
    int value(2);
    switch(value)
    {
        case tab[1]:
            cout << "result is: " << tab[0]<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However the compiler keeps telling me:

```
.../main.cpp|11|error: the value of ‘tab’ is not usable in a constant expression
```

Well I declared my array as "int const", isn't it enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every `case` statement must take a *constant-expression*, which is defined as:

> A *conditional-expression* *e* is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of *e*, following the rules of the
>   abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - [...]
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to
>
>   - a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a non-volatile const object with
>       a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression *[ Note:* a string literal (2.14.5)
>       corresponds to an array of such objects. *—end note ]*, or
>   - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a non-volatile object defined with `constexpr`, or that refers
>       to a non-mutable sub-object of such an object, or
>   - a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began
>       within the evaluation of e;
> - [...]

Your case is an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, but none of those three bullet points apply, so `tab[1]` is not a core constant expression. However, that second sub-bullet point offers us a clue: what if the object were defined with `constexpr`! That would make `tab[1]` a constant expression, and thus, this compiles:

```
constexpr int tab[3] = {1,2,3};
int value(2);
switch(value)
{
    case tab[1]:
        cout << "result is: " << tab[0]<< endl;
}
```

`const` doesn't make an object a constant expression. It just makes it non-mutable. Note that the following is totally valid code:

```
int x;
cin >> x;
const int y = x; // obviously, y can't be a constant expression
```

Comment: Why doesn't the first bullet point of the l.t.r condition apply?

Comment: @0x499602D2 `tab` isn't of integral or enumeration type. If it were `const int tab = 1;` you could do `case tab`.

Comment: So the conversion is applied to `tab` and not `tab[1]`?

Comment: @0x499602D2: they both have to be converted. The rules apply if *any* expression breaks the conditions. The fact that the full expression `tab[1]` is of integral type isn't enough, because evaluating the sub-expression `tab` still requires an rvalue conversion, and the abstract machine has to evaluate `tab` in order to evaluate `tab[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

No you don't need `const`, you need `constexpr`. Rewrite your code with :

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int tab[3] = {1,2,3};
    int value(2);
    switch(value)
    {
        case tab[1]:
            cout << "result is: " << tab[0]<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since you need value of `tab` at compile time it should be a `constexpr` expression. Also every `case` statement takes *constant-expression* **not** *constant-value*. `const` will make it *constant-value*, whereas `constexpr` will make it *constant-expression*.